# How to programmatically call the onPress() method of Pressable?

Tags: react-native

I want to call the `onPress()` method of my Pressable. How can I achieve this? I tried calling the `onPress()` method when I hit the second button via a ref but it did not work.

```js
const pressableRef = useRef(null);

return (
    <Pressable 
        style={{ width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }} 
        onPress={() => console.log('I want to print this')} 
        ref={pressableRef} 
    />
    <Button
        title="Klick me"
        onPress={() => {pressableRef.current.onPress()}
    />
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method with the name onPress on Pressable Component that you can call by reference. onPress is a prop you pass to the Pressable that accepts a function.

You can define a function before return so it can be available by both.

**Try this**

```
 const callPressableFunc = () => {
    console.log('I want to print this');
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Pressable
        style={{width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}
        onPress={callPressableFunc}
        ref={pressableRef}
      />
      <Button title="Klick me" onPress={callPressableFunc} />
    </View>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

my code not work in this situation, but i do some changes and it works for me :)

this is my code:

```
const ElementRef = createRef();
useEffect(() => {
        if (ElementRef.current) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                ElementRef.current?.scrollToIndex({
                    index: 3,
                    animated: true
                })
            }, 500);
        }
    }, [ElementRef])
```

// ...

```
<FlatList
                            nestedScrollEnabled
                            data={Calendar}
                            keyExtractor={item => item.visit_day_identity}
                            renderItem={renderItem}
                            horizontal
                            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                            snapToEnd
                            ref={ElementRef}
                        />
```